# Compose email using outlook 2013 with C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to compose and email and open the compose windows of the outlook 2013 using c#. Below is my code. It does not shows any error, but no windows opens up! Does anyone have an idea of what may be the issue:

```
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                mailItem.Subject = "This is the subject";
                mailItem.To = "someone@example.com";
                mailItem.Body = "This is the message.";
                //mailItem.Attachments.Add(logPath);//logPath is a string holding path to the log.txt file
                mailItem.Display(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close, you just need to set `mailItem.Display(true)` the below works for me:

```
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                mailItem.Subject = "This is the subject";
                mailItem.To = "someone@example.com";
                mailItem.Body = "This is the message.";
                //mailItem.Attachments.Add(logPath);//logPath is a string holding path to the log.txt file
                mailItem.Display(true) //THIS IS THE CHANGE;
```

Comment: yes, I actually tried that, but it didn't work on my system as it had an issue and needed a restart. Thank you.